# How to get location specific information in Open Street Map using the Overpass API?

Tags: location, coordinates, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have some trouble getting the query right to get information about a road an users is on at a given moment.

For example the user is driving a car and I want to get some information about the road the user is driving on every now and then.

I tried to use the `coord-query` to get location specific information, but I couldn't find any useful information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm-script>
   <coord-query lat="51.87810" lon="4.52587" />
   <print mode="body" />
</osm-script>
```

However when I try to run a `bbox-query`:

```
<query type="way">
  <has-kv k="maxspeed"/>
  <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
</query>
<union>
  <item/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
</union>
<print/>
```

I get a lot more useful information as a response such as name, oneway, bicycles allowed etc.

I am using [this](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) tool to test the queries.

My question is how I can achieve to get the information from the `bbox-query` out of a `coord-query`, so it will return only information about that specific location instead of also information about the streets around it?

Comment: What you try to do is reverse geocoding. Is there a specific reason, why you don't use Nominatim, the OSM default application for this scenario? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup

Comment: @MaM Thats not entirely correct. Reverse geocoding usually returns address information while he is interested in road-specific information. This is still possible via Nominatim, but requires to extract the way ID of the geocoding result and make another API call in order to obtain the required information.

Comment: Oh ok, I missunderstood that location means here just position. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no much [documentation for the `coord-query`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Query_for_Areas) and no [examples](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) but it looks like this query is for searching *areas* and not *ways*.

In my opinion a `bbox-query` might be more useful because you never have exact coordinates. Also keep in mind that at a particular coordinate there can be more than just one road, e.g. at intersections or roads passing above/under each other or being very close together.

So either way you will have to implement something for comparing several roads in order to decide which one is the most plausible one. This can be done for example by looking where you have been and where you area heading to and by comparing this information with the geometry of the surrounding roads. Likewise the first and last [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) of an OSM way will help you because connected ways always share the same nodes at the start or end.

Comment: For convenience, you could also use the around-selector (`<around lat="51.87810" lon="4.52587" radius="30"/>`): http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Bq But you still have to do some post-processing, as scai points out.